# Do browsers cache CDN scripts shared by different sites?

Tags: webserver, cors, browser-cache, cdn

Do browsers cache CDN scripts shared by different sites? If I've downloaded, say, jQuery from a CDN server for `example.com`, will it be reloaded for another site?

I guess, in other words the question is: should a web-server return the same content for the same URL, even if it's included in a different page? I presume here, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value is `*`.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any content URL would be independent from the browser's point of view.  This is one of the benefits (as you point out) of using the CDN version of popular libraries. As a content creator, your site will load faster if a visitor has already loaded the library through visiting another site.

Cross-Origin Request Sharing (CORS) headers would still be honored, so (again as you pointed out) any public CDN version of a library is also going to have liberal headers as by their very nature they are "third party" scripts in relation to your own site.

So if somebody tried to use "your" content as if it were a CDN, you would want to apply more restrictive CORS headers to prevent that. The browser would apply those and reject the usage of the previously cached content.